# Sort Python DataFrame by Day of the Week

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sort my dataframe by the day of the week in the index. I was able to create a workaround where I created an additional column that I manually assigned the correct order value to and then sorted. But there has to be a better way, especially when I'm dealing with potentially more date values.

```
dict = {'Monday': Monday/MonCount, 'Tuesday': Tuesday/TueCount, 'Wednesday': Wednesday/WedCount, 'Thursday': Thursday/ThuCount, 'Friday': Friday/FriCount}
df = pd.Series(dict, name='DailyValue')
dff = DataFrame(df)
dff['Day'] = dff.index
dff['Sorter'] = [5,1,4,2,3]

dff.sort_values(by = ['Sorter'], inplace = True) 
#dff.sort(['Day'], ascending = True) 

dff.plot(kind='bar', grid = True, y = ['DailyValue'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to generate the weekdays (i.e. 0-6) in your index, and then create a series from these values.  You sort this series by these weekday values and take the index.  You then use `ix` to index your original series based on this sorted index.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(14), index=pd.date_range('2016-1-1', periods=14))

s
Out[34]: 
2016-01-01    0.915488
2016-01-02   -1.053409
2016-01-03   -1.826033
2016-01-04    0.559250
2016-01-05   -0.278086
2016-01-06    0.041113
2016-01-07    1.076463
2016-01-08    0.942720
2016-01-09   -0.850388
2016-01-10   -0.649713
2016-01-11    2.769957
2016-01-12    0.498103
2016-01-13    1.098085
2016-01-14    0.699077
Freq: D, dtype: float64

idx = pd.Series([d.weekday() for d in s.index]).sort_values().index

s.ix[idx]
Out[36]: 
2016-01-04    0.559250
2016-01-11    2.769957
2016-01-05   -0.278086
2016-01-12    0.498103
2016-01-06    0.041113
2016-01-13    1.098085
2016-01-07    1.076463
2016-01-14    0.699077
2016-01-01    0.915488
2016-01-08    0.942720
2016-01-02   -1.053409
2016-01-09   -0.850388
2016-01-03   -1.826033
2016-01-10   -0.649713
dtype: float64
```

As a one liner...

```
s_new = s.ix[pd.Series([d.weekday() for d in s.index]).sort_values().index]
```

Exactly the same for a dataframe.

```
df_new = df.ix[pd.Series([d.weekday() for d in df.index]).sort_values().index]
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you. Is there a difference in the final product between a Series() and DataFrame() function?

Comment: No.  It is based on the index, so it should work fine for either a dataframe or a series.